# Is combinatorics a part of arithmetics?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I wonder how arithmetic, combinatorics and discrete mathematics are related.

Answer (score 1):

Whole the mathematics is unique, for the sake of simplicity of study, we have distributed mathematics in different fields.

Arithmetic is the study of numbers. What the numbers are for? Simple answer is - "numbers are for counting" .. and we do some operations on numbers for counting just as in combinatorics. So, Combinatorics and Arithmetic are closely related.

Now, Discrete means - not continuous. Clearly, When we count things they are not continuous. So, Combinatorics is a PART of Discrete Mathematics. For more information about that field, you can see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic involves operating on numbers using basic operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division (and possibly exponentiation).

Combinatorics involves counting things, usually things that are discrete. To count large numbers of things, addition, multiplication, subtraction and division are often involved.